# Events of jquery with TS - how to make it strict?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Say I have a trigger:

```
$(window).trigger('kittySaid', ['meow', true, 3]);
```

and somewhere else in code I have

```
$(window).on('kittySaid', (e, sound:string, isPurring:boolean, age:number)=>{ 
    do something
});
```

So the problem is: types in "trigger" do not check types in "on", so I can pass 123 instead of "meow" and won't get any warnings. Is it possible to make trigger check on's types as if I call a function?

Comment: Do you need to use an array of 3 values in one place and 4 separate arguments (the last 3 corresponding to the values in the array) in the other? That is a bit unfortunate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way that you can correlate the types, keeping them in sync as well as declaring their relationship.

```
type KittyEvent = 'kittySaid';

type KittySaidEventArguments = [string, boolean, number];

interface JQuery {
  trigger(name: KittyEvent, args: KittySaidEventArguments): void;

  on(
    name: KittyEvent,
    handler: (
      e: Event,
      sound: KittySaidEventArguments[0],
      isPurring: KittySaidEventArguments[1],
      age: KittySaidEventArguments[2]
    ) => void
  ): void;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. This requires TypeScript 2.1 but you should use 2.2 or later as many aspects of indexed access types have been refined.
2. If you are inside of a module, wrap the above `interface` portion of the above code in a `declare global {...}` block.